# xelatex -shell-escape permission

Tags: shell-escape

I'm quite confused what means `-shell-escape` option. I'm trying to beutify creating my tikz images (differently from editing PDFs in Photoshop). I'm using `xelatex` and TeXnicCenter. I haven't read shell escape enabling details anywhere. I thought that option is to put into `Command line arguments to pass the compiler` in `Define Output Profiles` in TeXnic.

[image: MiXtecCenter output profiles]

When I run some simple graphics through xelatex, no image is given (standalone convert=true). In log file there is (at the end):

```
runsystem(xelatex  -shell-escape  -jobname "import" "\expandafter\def\csname sa@internal@run\endcsname{1}\input{import}"
)...executed.

runsystem(imgconvert -density 300 import.pdf  -quality 90 image.png)...executed.



Class standalone Warning: Conversion failed! Please ensure that shell escape
(standalone)              is enabled (e.g. use '-shell-escape').
```

Please help!

Comment: Do you have the program `imgconvert` installed?

Comment: The message says "runsystem ... executed", so shell-escape was active. The conversion failed for another reason. Try to run the `imgconvert` command on the command line from your current directory to find out the reason.

Comment: It doesn't recognize that command. I've installed Image Magick. I renamed its executable as 'imgconvert' as suggested in standalone manual (page 17)... I suppose those images are saving in the same folder with tex file by default.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have zero knowledge with Windows so my question is if " ... executed" means that the run was successfull? Or does it only means that the command `runsystem` was _only_ called from within TeX, without any additional test?

Comment: @Herbert If I put `\immediate\write18{tlgrm update --list}` (remark the typo in tlgrm) then I see on the terminal the message that tlgrm can't be found and the log-file says `runsystem(tlgrm update --list)...executed.`. Without --shell-escape the log-file says `runsystem(tlgrm update --list)...disabled (restricted).`. So you can see in the log if the command was run but not if it was successfull.

Comment: @ussername: Did you add the path to imgconvert to your PATH-variable?

Comment: Definitely not. Where can I put it in TeXnicCenter - preprocessor, postprocessor...?

Comment: The path variable must be changed in your windowns settings. google for it if you don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I added Image Magick path to `Path Variable`, now I can launch IM from console (imgconvert command). TeXnicCenter settings remains the same. After compilation the outcome is unchanged, including those lines in log file.

Comment: Did you restart texnicCenter?

Comment: I did. Test commands from [Image Magick website](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows) already work for me (`convert logo: logo.gif`, `identify logo.gif`). I got new ![error message](http://i.imgur.com/kJNoJ1I.jpg) during compiling.

Comment: + [log file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxA-dFcRfP61RTJQWDZ5X0FsNk0/edit?pli=1)

Answer (score 3):

With MiKTeX, the command-line parameter is `--enable-write18`. As pointed by Herbert, MiKTeX understands also `--shell-escape`, but you must write *two* dashes at the beginning.

Comment: MikTeX also understands `-shell-escape`

Comment: @Herbert: In this case the problem might come from writing only one dash at the beginning?

Comment: -shell-escape, --shell-escape, -enable-write18, --enable-write18 always the same result as above

Comment: If you try to compile from the console, what's happening? And with another editor, say TeXstudio or TeXmaker?

Comment: From console and TeXworks (with xelatex shell escape option), those log lines look alike (from console launched as administrator there is `disabled (restricted)` instead of `executed`).

Comment: With `pdflatex` in TeXnicCenter, there is:  
 `Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!`