# Standalone convert does not produce png

Tags: standalone, png

I have the following example code:

```
\documentclass[convert={convertexe={convert.exe}}]{standalone}

\begin{document}

 hello

\end{document}
```

The addition of "convert={convertexe={convert.exe}}" is added as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93891/conversion-problem-using-standalone-and-imagemagick). I want to convert the outcome into a .png file.

I use the following command

```
pdflatex --shell-escape Test.tex
```

as suggested in the standalone package manual [section 4.6.2](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf).

But then I get the following error message:

```
runsystem(pdflatex  -shell-escape  -jobname "Test" "\expandafter\def\csname sa@
internal@run\endcsname{1}\input{Test}")...executed.
runsystem(convert.exe -density 300 Test.pdf  -quality 90 Test.png)...executed.
Class standalone Warning: Conversion unsuccessful!
(standalone)              There might be something wrong with your
(standalone)              conversation software or the file permissions!
```

I have updated ImageMagick to version 6.8.9.

I have found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187214/xelatex-shell-escape-permission) with a similar problem, but the solutions provided do not help me or the author. Hopefully someone can help me now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you call "convert.exe -density 300 Test.pdf -quality 90 Test.png" on the commandline. Is convert.exe included in your PATH-variable?

Comment: And is `convert` included in your PATH before the os command to convert from FAT to NTFS?

Comment: @ Uwe Ziegenhagen: This gives exactly the same error message, and no .png file is created. During the installation process of ImageMagick it was asked to add it to PATH. Command 'echo %PATH%' indeed shows the ImageMagick folder.

Answer (score 2):

Find an exe file - magick.exe, then make two copies of it with name "covert.exe"  "imgconvert.exe" in the same folder. Then run your command again.

You can find the file in the folder of ImageMagick, which is "C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-7.0.6-Q16" for me.

You get this error because the new version of ImageMagick changed the name of "covert.exe" to "magick.exe" while the standalone package didn't know that. For the file "imgcovert.exe", it maybe needed for windows user for some standalone text file to avoid another convert.exe in windows.

Comment: Convert.exe was a very unspecified name anyway. I appreciate the change. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the imgconvert and magick commands work in your system command prompt, changing the convert option to be "convert={convertexe={magick.exe}}" should work.